# VBA - If value in sheet1 found in sheet2, then delete data from sheet2

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have 2 sheets setup: Exclusions and Issues

**Issues** has a list of CASE ID's and Columns that list the "Issue"

**Exclusions** will be populated with CASE ID's that are to be excluded (and removed) from the Issues sheet.

My question is 2 fold:

1. Is my current code handling this correctly? Are there any ways to improve this?
2. Is there a way to have the code cycle through all columns dynamically? Or is it just easier to copy the FOR/NEXT loop for each column on the "Issues" sheet?

Code below:

```
Sub Exclusions()

'find exclusions and remove from issues sheet. once done delete any completely blank row

Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastrowex As Long
Dim DeleteRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Issues").ShowAllData
    Sheets("Exclusions").ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastrowex = Sheets("Exclusions").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

    With ThisWorkbook

        lastrow = Sheets("Issues").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For k = 2 To lastrowex
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            If Sheets("Exclusions").Cells(k, 10).Value <> "" Then
                If Sheets("Exclusions").Cells(k, 10).Value = Sheets("Issues").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                    Sheets("Issues").Cells(i, 11).ClearContents
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next k

    End With


On Error Resume Next

For Each rng In Range("B2:P" & lastrow).Columns
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Next rng

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Data Format:

"Issues" sheet

```
CASE ID      Issue 1     Issue 2    Issue 3
ABC123       No address  No Name    No Number
```

"Exclusions" sheet

```
Issue 1    Issue 2    Issue 3
ABC123     DEF123     ABC123
```

Data Example:

Issues sheet may have several CASE ID's present for one or multiple issues.

```
CASE ID   Issue 1     Issue 2    Issue 3
DEF123    No add                 No num
PLZ                   No name
```

Exclusions sheet is basically a method for someone to "exclude" a particular issue for whatever reason. So if it is determined that PLZ CASE ID's not having a name is OK, then it is to be excluded from showing up on the Issues sheet.

```
Issue 1      Issue 2     Issue 3
DEF123                   DEF123
```

PLZ would not show up in the above example because it is in the "EXCLUSIONS" sheet.

Comment: Is your code "working"?  If so, you'd have better luck on Code Review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it seems to be, yes. but i know there's a better way to do it. also i dont know how to have the code run through all columns instead of repeating the for/next loop for all 10+ columns that will keep increasing as time goes on..

Comment: Then you should use Code Review.

Comment: Rather than nested loops for sheet row comparison, you could just use filter and remove cell contents. Even better, capture data from `Exclusions` sheet into and array and then perform filter on  `Issues` sheet. Saying all that, this should be in code review site

Comment: I've posted it there based on everyone's recommendation but the response times are so much slower. If anyone might have any input that would be awesome.

Comment: @Zac: Not sure how to go about this?

Comment: Can you explain the logic to exlude the issues with an example?

Comment: Using the the above Data Format portion as an example: ABC123 has No address/name/number. If the front-end staff determine this is acceptable (for whatever reason) they would go under each issue column (in the Exclusions sheet) and simply type in that CASE ID there. So for ex: Issue 1 - ABC123. This would mean omit ABC123 from being visible under Issue 1 on the Issues sheet.

Comment: 1) Please add another example. it's not clear for me because the way you have the information in columns. 2) is it possible to convert the information into Excel Structured Tables? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-format-tables-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664

Comment: @RicardoDiaz added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBAWARD Make a copy of your data before trying this code:

You need to adapt it to your needs. I didn't quite understood when is the row gonna be empty. Any way, working with ranges may be faster and easier to debug.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Exclusions()

'find exclusions and remove from issues sheet. once done delete any completely blank row

    ' Declare objects
    Dim issuesRange As Range
    Dim exclusionsRange As Range
    Dim issuesCell As Range
    Dim exclusionsCell As Range

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim lastRowIssues As Long
    Dim lastRowExclusions As Long


    ' This is not recommended
    On Error Resume Next
        Sheets("Issues").ShowAllData
        Sheets("Exclusions").ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    ' Get the last row in the exclusions sheet - In this case I'd prefer to work with structured tables
    lastRowExclusions = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exclusions").Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row ' use full identifier with ThisWorkbook. and also use Worksheets collection as you don't need to look for graphics sheets

    ' Get the last row in the issues sheet - In this case I'd prefer to work with structured tables
    lastRowIssues = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Issues").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Store Exclusions in a range
    Set exclusionsRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exclusions").Range("J2:L" & lastRowExclusions)

    ' Store Issues in a range
    Set issuesRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Issues").Range("A2:C" & lastRowIssues)

    ' Loop through each of the exclusions
    For Each exclusionsCell In exclusionsRange

        ' Loop through each of the Issues Cells
        For Each issuesCell In issuesRange

            ' Compare if ex is equal to iss
            If exclusionsCell.Value = issuesCell Then

                ' Color the cell or clear its contents
                'issuesCell.Interior.Color = 255

                ' Clear the cell contents
                 issuesCell.ClearContents

                ' Delete the whole row?
                'issuesCell.Rows.EntireRow.Delete

                ' Delete the row if it's empty
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Issues").Range("B" & issuesCell.Row & ":D" & issuesCell.Row).Value) = 0 Then
                    issuesCell.Rows.EntireRow.Delete
                End If

            End If

        Next issuesCell

    Next exclusionsCell

    ' Restore settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: i tried using this but it crashed my excel instance. is it because of the loops through all the columns between 2 sheets? managed to use certain parts though :)

Comment: it's looping only over J to L columns in exclusions sheet and over A to C in issues sheet. It's not supposed to crash. try running the code with F8 (step by step) and see if you can identify in what line does it crash.